# AlarmManager does not work in foreground service, when app was killed

Tags: java, android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

My application should send notifications at the specified time.
 I wrote a service that uses AlarmManager, a receiver that restarts it if you close the application. The service is restarted (as can be seen in the logs), but AlarmManager does not work (the receiver does not receive an intent from it) while the application is closed. I also tried to register the receiver in the service code - it still does not work (
AlarmService - foreground service. AlarmSetter - class to set Alarms.
AlarmReceiver - receiver to send notifications (has log: intent received)

Manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="net.ozero.drugsreminder"
            android:installLocation="internalOnly">

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

            <application
                android:name=".App"
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                >

                <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name=".activities.AddPrescActivity"
                    android:label="@string/label_add_presc_activity"
                    android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity"
                    android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name=".activities.AddDrugActivity"
                    android:label="@string/label_add_drug_activity"
                    android:parentActivityName=".activities.AddPrescActivity"
                    android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme"
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <activity android:name=".activities.AlarmActivity">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>

                <service
                    android:name=".services.AlarmService"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:exported="true" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="net.ozero.drugsreminder.services.AlarmService.MarkEvent" />
                        <action android:name="net.ozero.drugsreminder.services.AlarmService.SetLater" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </service>
                <receiver
                    android:name=".services.AlarmReceiver"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:exported="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="net.ozero.drugsreminder.services.AlarmReceiver" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
                <receiver
                    android:name=".services.RestartAlarmServiceReceiver"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:exported="true">
                </receiver>
                <receiver
                    android:name=".services.BootCompleteReceiver"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:exported="true">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>
            </application>

        </manifest>
```

AlarmService:

```
    package net.ozero.drugsreminder.services;

        import android.app.AlarmManager;
        import android.app.NotificationManager;
        import android.app.Service;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.IBinder;
        import android.util.Log;

        import net.ozero.drugsreminder.alarm.AlarmSetter;
        import net.ozero.drugsreminder.database.DBHelper;
        import net.ozero.drugsreminder.datastructure.Event;
        import net.ozero.drugsreminder.formatters.AlarmMessageBuilder;

        import java.util.List;

        import static net.ozero.drugsreminder.App.*;
        import static net.ozero.drugsreminder.App.EXTRA_ALARM_ID;

        /**TODO alarm repeating (bug) */
        public class AlarmService extends Service {

            public AlarmService() {
            }

            public DBHelper mDBHelper;
            public AlarmReceiver mAlarmReceiver;
            public AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

            @Override
            public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

                Log.i("AlarmService:", "on start");

        //        mAlarmReceiver = new AlarmReceiver();

                mDBHelper = new DBHelper(this);

                //set event is done
                if (isMarkAction(intent)) {
                    markEvent(intent);
                }

                //set event to alarm later
                if (isSetLaterAction(intent)) {
                    setEventLater(intent);
                }
                setAlarms();

                return START_STICKY;
            }

            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
                Log.i("AlarmService:", "on removed");
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(this, RestartAlarmServiceReceiver.class));

                Log.i(getClass().getName(), "OnTaskRemoves: broadcast sent");

                super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
            }

            private boolean isMarkAction(Intent intent) {
                return (
                        intent != null
                        && intent.getAction() != null
                        && intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_MARK_EVENT)
                );
            }

            private boolean isSetLaterAction(Intent intent) {
                return (
                        intent != null
                                && intent.getAction() != null
                                && intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SET_LATER)
                );
            }

            private void setEventLater(Intent intent) {
                int id = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ALARM_ID, 0);
                mDBHelper.setEventLater(id, ALARM_INTERVAL);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                assert notificationManager != null;
                notificationManager.cancel(id);
                Log.i("AlarmService:", "event time set later : " + id);
            }

            private void markEvent(Intent intent) {
                int id = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ALARM_ID, 0);
                mDBHelper.markEvent(id);
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                assert notificationManager != null;
                notificationManager.cancel(id);
                Log.i("AlarmService:", "event is marked, id : " + id);
            }

            private void setAlarms() {

                mDBHelper = new DBHelper(this);

                List<Event> events = mDBHelper.getActualEvents();

                Log.i("AlarmService:setAlarms:", "actual (not marked) events size:" + String.valueOf(events.size()));

                AlarmSetter alarmSetter = new AlarmSetter(this);
                AlarmMessageBuilder alarmMessageBuilder = new AlarmMessageBuilder(mDBHelper);

                for (Event event : events) {

                    long timeMillis = event.getReceptionDateTime().getTime();
                    String message = alarmMessageBuilder.getMessage(event);
                    int id = event.getId();

                    alarmSetter.setAlarm(timeMillis, message, id);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();

                Log.i(getClass().getName(), "onDestroy");
            }
        }
```

AlarmSetter:

```
    package net.ozero.drugsreminder.alarm;

        import android.app.AlarmManager;
        import android.app.PendingIntent;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Build;
        import android.util.Log;

        import net.ozero.drugsreminder.services.AlarmReceiver;

        import static net.ozero.drugsreminder.App.EXTRA_ALARM_ID;
        import static net.ozero.drugsreminder.App.EXTRA_ALARM_MESSAGE;

        public class AlarmSetter {

            //one minute timeout
            public static final long DEFAULT_ALARM_TIMEOUT = 60*1000L;

            private Context mContext;
            private AlarmManager mAlarmManager;

            public AlarmSetter(Context applicationContext) {
                mContext = applicationContext;
                mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Log.i("AlarmSetter:", "alarm manager:" + mAlarmManager);
            }

            //main method
            public void setAlarm(long timeMillis, String message, int id) {

                //creating intent for alarm message
                Intent intent = new Intent("net.ozero.drugsreminder.services.AlarmReceiver");
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ALARM_MESSAGE, message);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ALARM_ID, id);

                //creating pending intent
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        mContext.getApplicationContext(), id, intent, 0);

                //setting alarm
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    mAlarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(
                            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            timeMillis,
                            pendingIntent
                    );
                } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    mAlarmManager.setExact(
                            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            timeMillis,
                            pendingIntent
                    );
                } else {
                    mAlarmManager.set(
                            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                            timeMillis,
                            pendingIntent
                    );
                }

                Log.i("AlarmSetter:" , "alarm set");
            }

        }
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
    package net.ozero.drugsreminder.services;

        import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.util.Log;

        import net.ozero.drugsreminder.alarm.NotificationSetter;

        import static net.ozero.drugsreminder.App.EXTRA_ALARM_ID;
        import static net.ozero.drugsreminder.App.EXTRA_ALARM_MESSAGE;

        public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                Log.i("AlarmReceiver:", "notification received");

                String message = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ALARM_MESSAGE);
                int id = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_ALARM_ID, 1);
                NotificationSetter notificationSetter = new NotificationSetter(context);
                notificationSetter.setNotification(message, id);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run your service as a real foreground service so that it will survive even if your app has been closed or finished.

This is a very  simple sample from http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getText(R.string.ticker_text),
        System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getText(R.string.notification_title),
        getText(R.string.notification_message), pendingIntent);
startForeground(ONGOING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll try it)

Comment: I understood - it will show the notification ? and i don't need it. There is an mistake in my question - AlarmService - has to be background service. When app is killed it restarted but doesn't work(